# Why do MacOS apps store a lot of strings?

Tags: string, macos, executable

Why is it that in MacOS, my application has lots of strings in the executable. Like it's like a bunch of binary non-human-readable nonsense, then I see a bunch of function and variable names, type names, like `NSString` and other `NS`+something strings, a lot of `OBJC`+something IIRC, but why? Why does it store all that? Other than bloating the executable size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't *specifically* answer this for MacOS binaries, but there are generally 2 reasons for a binary to have things like function names:

1. It allows someone to debug the program. Without these symbols, every variable, function, stacktrace would contain information that's not that useful.
2. It allows in some cases for other processes to call functions inside another binary. If the function name is not encoded, it's not possible for some other program to call that function by its name (because it doesn't have one).

It's often possible to create binaries stripped with debug symbols, which would reduce the binary size.

Comment: It also leads to a more useful system crash report.

Comment: But how can I get rid of them, so I don't have to go out of my way for 1 or 2 character variable names?